# Execute jni in Maven ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, java-native-interface

I have to call native function from Java with JNI and Maven on Ubuntu 14.04. I have generated `.so` file and I don't know how to specify in Maven `pom.xml` file to access `.so` file. I searched about this and I got the following link: [Calling native functions from Java with JNI and Maven](http://www.tricoder.net/blog/?p=197)

So, as per the link should I create multiple `pom.xml` files to execute?

Also, I came across posts suggest to use plugin such as NAR plugin to execute JNI with Maven. Please guide me on how to execute JNI with Maven on Ubuntu.